# Unable to receive HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted in WSO2 esb proxy service deployed in cloud

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

---

I am using a proxy service, deployed in cloud, to add message to an ActiveMQ Queue
I have used these 2 properties in the insequence:

```xml
 <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
 <property name="FORCE_SC_ACCEPTED" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
```

But, When I hit the proxy service with SOAP UI I am getting a timeout.

The same proxy works perfectly well on my local machine.

Comment: Are you sure the request is coming into your proxy service from SoapUI? Place a log mediator in your proxy and see whether the request hits the proxy.

Comment: yes the request goes through the proxy I have used a log mediator.
Even the queue is receiving the message.

Comment: @RajkumarRajaratnam Is there any default configuration in the configuration files(Axis.xml) that might have been changed in the Cloud server...???

Comment: I don't think it is related to any configuration changes in axis2.xml. However you can a tool to compare both repository/conf folders to see where there are any configuration changes. For example, use meld (http://meldmerge.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in WSO2 I created a tenant in my local machine and created the proxy service on this tenant and hit the service using SoapUI and I did not get any 202 response back.

Previously on my local I was doing it as a super tenant.